# Styling datatable "Search"

Tags: css, datatables

I am trying to style the "Search" along with its associated input but it won't respond.

When I inspect the element I can see datatable filter and info are styled the same. My CSS change (font size) gets applied to info, below the table, but search text and input are not cooperating. I used .6rem as font-size to easily verify font size is applied.

This is what I added (I tried both with and without the "div"):

```
.dataTables_info, .dataTables_filter > label, .dataTables_filter > input {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .6em;
}

div.dataTables_info, div.dataTables_filter > label, div.dataTables_filter > input {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .6em;
}
```

I made sure custom CSS file is loaded after datatable's own CSS.

Also tried:

```
$('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').css(
    {'font-size': '.6rem'}
);
```

And:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter > label, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter > input {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .6em;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the link to the demo or create one here?

Comment: its an intranet app.

Comment: tried a couple of other things and edited question

Comment: It's hard to answer unless we look into the code directly. Anything else can override it.

Comment: What is confusing is why datatable-info at the bottom of the table changes font but not the "Search" text or input. I will look more to see if there are any other references to datatable "filter".

Comment: Can we confirm that my CSS changes are correct? Is this, theoretically, correct way of changing the datatable filter styles?

Comment: The one with "wrapper" worked, I just had to add "!important" after font size.

Comment: Kind of. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity You can see the usage of `!important`

Answer (score 2):

Using this:

```css
div.dataTables_filter > label > input {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .6em;
}
```

...works for me.

Using a css selector like `.dataTables_filter > input` will not work. It assumes that the input is a *direct child* (`>`) of the `dataTables_filter` div - but it isn't, because there is an intervening `<label>` element:

[image]

You should be able to avoid needing to use `!important`, also, this way.

Comment: "div" didn;t work for me but .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter > label, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter > label > input worked for info and input but not for label itself (the "Search" text)

Comment: OK understood.  Using your approach gives me a label displayed using the smaller font (i.e. it works correctly for me).  Also the fact that `<div>` did not work for you suggests you have something different from the standard/vanilla DataTables layout.